# Prevent Multiple Form Submissions, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, captcha

I have a form, something like:

```
<form action="" method="post">

    <label class="reg_label" for="name">Name:</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" class="text_area" id="name"/>

    .... etc...
</form>
```

To submit the form, the user must also first complete a CAPTCHA. This works great, and only allows form submission for perfect matches. Reloading the page will result in a new CAPTCHA. Pressing the "back" button will also display a new CAPTCHA.

When the user submits the form, it is verified via javascript, and that all works dandy, and then it is submitted (and emailed) via a separate php script:

```
<?php
    include('connect_to_mysql.php');                
    $webMaster = 'my@email.com';

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST["name"]);
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST["phone"]);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST["email"]);
    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST["message"]);

    $emailSubject = 'Contact Form Submission';

    $body = <<<EOD

Name:     $name
Email:    $email 
Phone:    $phone

Message:  

$message
EOD;

    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

    header('Location: ../thankyou.html');

?>
```

This all works as expected, and I am satisfied with the escape strings for now. The form catches non-emails, and the CAPTCHA works every time. But some clown just sent me **128 SIMULTANEOUS** form submissions, and I am wondering how this individual did it.

Every field was filled out "9999.9". When I try it, I get errors for the name, phone number and email. I can't even submit the form with that data. Even if I could, I would only be able to send it once because of the CAPTCHA (PHP).

The only hole I can see, and it IS a hole (just tried it), is to type in the URL of the external script directly. So, a bad guy could write his own script, assign the variables (to POST) and then call my contact function 128 times.

While I'm working on righting that wrong, are there any other obvious gaping holes that someone could use for multiple form submissions like that, while bypassing the CAPTCHA (which is PHP)? Obviously just turn off JS to get around the validation.

I can post more code if needed, but just assume the JS is turned off, leaving only the PHP CAPTCHA check - which has nothing to do with the actual submission of the form, and changes on BOTH "back" and "reload" operations.

Thanks in advance.

**CAPTCHA CODE**

*Captcha.php*

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $rand = md5(rand(0,999)); 
    $value = substr($rand, 10, 5);
    $_SESSION['cap_key'] = $value;

    ... do some drawing stuff to make the CAPCHA, which is an IMAGE and cannot be read without some fancy character-recogntion code...
?>
```

*Within the contact form file (called when form submitted)*

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if ($_POST['submit']) 
    {       
        if ($_POST['captcha'] == $_SESSION['cap_key']) // Success
        {   
            include('scripts/contact.php');

        }else if($cap != 'Eq') // If wrong captcha entered
        {
            ... reload page after sanitizing the inputs...
        }
    }
?>
```

But like I said, the CAPTCHA changes every reload of the page.

Thanks again.

Comment: he probably did it using a script, not using a browser, so he didn't go through the Javascript validation. That's why you should always do validation on the server as well.

Comment: If the captcha resets when the form itself reloads, what happens if I just hit submit multiple times, opening a new window each time? You could always amend your sending code so that it deletes the captcha value from the session after sending the email.

Comment: @Barmar I am fixing that right now. I also had obvious folder names (i.e. "scripts") and no htaccess or index.php within the folder to prevent the baddies from seeing inside. They could have easily found the script that way.

Comment: @andrewsi How would you submit multiple times and open a new window each time? And duly noted with deleting the session variable.

Comment: @Birrel - depending on the browser, you can hit the Control key when you click a button and the submission page opens in a new window

Comment: This could be of use http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Preventing-Multiple-Submits.html it has served me well before.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I didn't know you could do that. This is exciting stuff, my first nefarious attack against myself! Now how do I track the guy who did it and make his computer blow up? ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- that's great. Similar to how the CAPTCHA is working, and I'm unsetting that now upon form submission.

Comment: @Birrel - once the email is sent, set the session variable for the captcha to a unique value that your captcha can't itself generate. Then, in your code, you can check for that value in the session, and see if this submission is in fact a repeat. That way, you can silently ignore it, and the miscreant assumes that it's worked.

Comment: @andrewsi that's good too! Very clever.